# Websphere node sync fails

Tags: java, web, synchronization, pipe, websphere-8

I need your help guys

I'm deploying an application on websphere 8.5 and I get an error when trying to sunc the node:

```
9/19/14 17:31:41:961 CEST]  

FFDC Exception:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.servlet.FileT
ransferServlet.safeClose ProbeId:2136 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.servlet.FileTransferServlet@8c12ef98
com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.write(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:188)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTOutputStream.write(SRTOutputStream.java:97)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.writeOut(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:590)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.write(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:374)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.finish(GZIPOutputStream.java:110)
        at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:151)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.servlet.FileTransferServlet.safeClose(FileTransferServlet.java:2134)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.servlet.FileTransferServlet.sendFile(FileTransferServlet.java:1789)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.servlet.FileTransferServlet.doGet(FileTransferServlet.java:657)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1048)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:716)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:412)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1066)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 32  Broken pipe
```

Have you any idea about the root cause please?

I already deplyed and started the same `EAR` file for the dev environment on the same `server`.

Thank you for your help!!

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation i found that my problem was cause by space lack on the FS.

The issue was solved by increasing the disk space capacity.

regards.